# Establishing a write lock on a row in hbase

Tags: hadoop, nosql, hbase

I am trying to test a workflow where the change i made reordered the deletes and how it cleans up the other indices from hbase.

There are 3 different indices being deleted. The logic somehow roughly resembles this operation.

```
try{

   try{
     hTable.delete(firstIndexDeletes);
   } catch(IOException ie) {
   // clean up and exception handling for first index
   }
   //more processing logic for second index
   try{
      hTable.delete(secondIndexDeletes)  
   } catch(IOException ie) {
   // Clean up and exception handling for second index 
   }
   //more processing logic
   hTable.delete(thirdIndex);
} catch(IOException ie) {
  //Clean up and exception handling for third index
}
```

I am trying to test the exception handling part via integration tests (i was able to get it tested throughly via unit tests) and i am trying to make the delete thrown an exception and i decided to use a lock on a specific index so that if an delete happens on that row it will throw an exception.

```
hTable.lockRow(Bytes.toBytes(firstIndexKey));
```

ideally i expected it to throw an exception for that row when it was deleted as part of firstIndexDeletes but somehow it just doesn't make any difference in my tests, it's not going to the exception handling part like i wanted. Is there something elementary i am missing?

Comment: Not up-voting to preserve your score..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge (from routine, close examination of the source) explicit row locks are being retired from HBase.  That said I've never tried to use them.

In my opinion, I would expect thorough unit test coverage (where you can exploit mocking) to be sufficient.

Comment: Is there any other way, I have unit tested all fail over scenarios through mocking

Comment: anyways we figured we'd discontinue that approach since they are deprecated in the api.